# In a setup.py involving Cython, if install_requires, then how can from library import something?

Tags: python, pip, cython, setup.py

This doesn't make sense to me. How can I use the setup.py to install Cython and then also use the setup.py to compile a library proxy?

```
import sys, imp, os, glob
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize # this isn't installed yet

setup(
    name='mylib',
    version='1.0',
    package_dir={'mylib': 'mylib', 'mylib.tests': 'tests'},
    packages=['mylib', 'mylib.tests'],
    ext_modules = cythonize("mylib_proxy.pyx"), #how can we call cythonize here?
    install_requires=['cython'],
    test_suite='tests',
)
```

Later:
python setup.py build

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ImportError: No module named Cython.Build
```

It's because cython isn't installed yet.

What's odd is that a great many projects are written this way.  A quick github search reveals as much: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=install_requires+cython&type=Code

Answer (score 13):

As I understand it, this is where [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) comes in - also see [some clarifications](https://snarky.ca/clarifying-pep-518/) by one of its authors.

The idea is that you add yet another file to your Python project / package: `pyproject.toml`. It is supposed to contain information on build environment dependencies (among other stuff, long term). `pip` (or just any other package manager) could look into this file and *before running setup.py* (or any other build script) install the required build environment. A `pyproject.toml` could therefore look like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython"]
```

It is a fairly recent development and, as of yet (January 2019), it is not finalized / approved by the Python community, though (limited) [support was added to pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4144) in May 2017 / the 10.0 release.

Answer (score 3):

One solution to this is to not make Cython a build requirement, and instead distribute the Cython generated `C` files with your package.  I'm sure there is a simpler example somewhere, but this is what `pandas` does - it conditionally imports Cython, and if not present can be built from the c files.

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3ff845b4e81d4dde403c29908f5a9bbfe4a87788/setup.py#L433

Edit:  The doc link from @danny has an easier to follow example.
http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules

Comment: This is the best answer and [is what is recommended by Cython documentation as well](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules). In general, pyx files do not need to be re-evaluated at install time, only if their source code changes. So for distributable packages only the Cython generated C/C++ files need to be distributed and built by setup.py.

Answer (score 2):

When you use setuptool, you should add `cython` to `setup_requires` (and also to `install_requires` if cython is used by installation), i.e.

```
# don't import cython, it isn't yet there
from setuptools import setup, Extension

# use Extension, rather than cythonize (it is not yet available)
cy_extension = Extension(name="mylib_proxy", sources=["mylib_proxy.pyx"])

setup(
    name='mylib',
    ...
    ext_modules = [cy_extension],
    setup_requires=["cython"],
    ...
)
```

`Cython` isn't imported (it is not yet available when `setup.py`starts), but `setuptools.Extension` is used  instead of `cythonize` to add cython-extension to the setup.

It should work now. The reason: [`setuptools` will try to import cython](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/a94ccbf404a79d56f9b171024dee361de9a948da/setuptools/command/build_ext.py#L15), after `setup_requires` are fulfilled:

```
...
try:
    # Attempt to use Cython for building extensions, if available
    from Cython.Distutils.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext
    # Additionally, assert that the compiler module will load
    # also. Ref #1229.
    __import__('Cython.Compiler.Main')
except ImportError:
    _build_ext = _du_build_ext
...
```

It becomes more complicated, if your Cython-extension uses `numpy`, but also this is possible - see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54117786/5769463).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense in general. It is, as you suspect, an attempt to use something that (possibly) has yet to be installed. If tested on a system that already has the dependency installed, you might not notice this defect. But run it on a system where your dependency is absent, and you will certainly notice.

There is another `setup()` keyword argument, `setup_requires`, that can appear to be parallel in form and use to `install_requires`, but this is an illusion. Whereas `install_requires` triggers a lovely ballet of automatic installation in environments that lack the dependencies it names, `setup_requires` is more documentation than automation. It won't auto-install, and certainly not magically jump back in time to auto-install modules that have already been called for in `import` statements.

There's more on this at [the setuptools docs](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html), but the quick answer is that you're right to be confused by a module that is trying to auto-install its own *setup* pre-requisites.

For a practical workaround, try installing `cython` separately, and then run this setup. While it won't fix the metaphysical illusions of this setup script, it will resolve the requirements and let you move on.

Comment: What's weird is a great many projects use code as I wrote it.  A quick search on GitHub reveals tons of them.  Has no one tested their code on a fresh install? https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=install_requires+cython&type=Code

Comment: It's not super convenient to do so. Large support packages (e.g. `cython`, `lxml`, `pandas`) often become insidious expectations. Many test on Travis CI, or locally with virtual environments, `tox`, etc. But these build environments get *custom install procedures* that aren't present just running the setup manually from scratch. It's easy to have gloriously running tests--auto-builds across a dozen different Python versions, with 100% coverage--that don't properly install from scratch from `setup.py` alone. Been there, done that. Embarrassing, annoying, and all too easy.