# Add numpy.get_include() argument to setuptools without preinstalled numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cython, setuptools

I am currently developing a python package that uses `cython` and `numpy` and I want the package to be installable using the `pip install` command from a clean python installation. All dependencies should be installed automatically. I am using `setuptools` with the following `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

my_c_lib_ext = setuptools.Extension(
    name="my_c_lib",
    sources=["my_c_lib/some_file.pyx"]
)

setuptools.setup(
    name="my_lib",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Me",
    author_email="me@myself.com",
    description="Some python library",
    packages=["my_lib"],
    ext_modules=[my_c_lib_ext],
    setup_requires=["cython >= 0.29"],
    install_requires=["numpy >= 1.15"],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent"
    ]
)
```

This has worked great so far. The `pip install` command downloads `cython` for the build and is able to build my package and install it together with `numpy`.

Now I want to improve the performance of my `cython` code, which leads to some changes in my `setup.py`. I need to add `include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]` to either the call of `setuptools.Extension(...)` or `setuptools.setup(...)` which means that I also need to `import numpy`. (See http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html and [Make distutils look for numpy header files in the correct place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379898/make-distutils-look-for-numpy-header-files-in-the-correct-place) for rationals.)

This is bad. Now the user cannot call `pip install` from a clean environment, because `import numpy` will fail. The user needs to `pip install numpy` before installing my library. Even if I move `"numpy >= 1.15"` from `install_requires` to `setup_requires` the installation fails, because the `import numpy` is evaluated earlier.

Is there a way to evaluate the `include_dirs` at a later point of the installation, for example, after the dependencies from `setup_requires` or `install_requires` have been resolved? I really like to have all dependencies resolved automatically and I dont want the user to type multiple `pip install` commands.

The following snippet works, but it is not officially supported because it uses an undocumented (and private) method:

```
class NumpyExtension(setuptools.Extension):
    # setuptools calls this function after installing dependencies
    def _convert_pyx_sources_to_lang(self):
        import numpy
        self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
        super()._convert_pyx_sources_to_lang()

my_c_lib_ext = NumpyExtension(
    name="my_c_lib",
    sources=["my_c_lib/some_file.pyx"]
)
```

The article [How to Bootstrap numpy installation in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919905/how-to-bootstrap-numpy-installation-in-setup-py) proposes using a `cmdclass` with custom `build_ext` class. Unfortunately, this breaks the build of the `cython` extension because `cython` also customizes `build_ext`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Bootstrap numpy installation in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919905/how-to-bootstrap-numpy-installation-in-setup-py)

Comment: @ead This does not work because `cython` also customizes `build_ext`. If I use the proposed solution, the `cython` build fails with `Don't know how to compile my_c_lib/some_file.pyx`, which means that the customized `build_ext` command of `cython` is not used anymore.

Comment: I see it is not that straight forward...

Comment: Look at what pybind11 does [here](https://github.com/pybind/python_example/blob/2ed5a68759cd6ff5d2e5992a91f08616ef457b5c/setup.py#L9) to defer the import - haven't tested but I think similar would work here.

Comment: The trick from pybind11 works after a small change. I had to inherit from `os.PathLike` instead of `object`, because `cython` requires a `str`, `bytes`, or `PathLike` object and `str`/`bytes` do not work because they are immutable. Do you want to create an answer from your comment oder should I self-answer my question?

Comment: @chrisb nice trick, but maybe a bit too clever: Should for example `build_ext` log options before requirements are installed, it will fail. On the other hand `Command.finalize_options` is the right place to handle such things - for a proper solution one should figure out, how it can work with Cython.

Comment: With recent enough pip, there might be solutions based on the use of the  `requires` element  of  the `[build-system]` section of a `pyproject.toml` file. That file might also need to specify a "build backend". For instance: `build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First question, when is `numpy` needed? It is needed during the setup (i.e. when `build_ext`-funcionality is called) and in the installation, when the module is used. That means `numpy` should be in `setup_requires` **and** in `install_requires`.

There are following alternatives to solve the issue for the setup:

1. using PEP [517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/)/[518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) (which is more straight forward IMO)
2. using `setup_requires`-argument of `setup` and postponing  import of `numpy` until setup's requirements are satisfied (which is not the case at the start of `setup.py`'s execution)

---

### **PEP 517/518-solution:**

Put next to `setup.py` a `pyproject.toml`-file , with the following content:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython>=0.29", "numpy >= 1.15"]
```

which defines packages needed for building, and then install using `pip install .` in the folder with `setup.py`. A disadvantage of this method is that `python setup.py install` no longer works, as it is `pip` that reads `pyproject.toml`. However, I would use this approach whenever possible.

---

### **Postponing import**

This approach is more complicated and somewhat hacky, but works also without `pip`.

First, let's take a look at unsuccessful tries so far:

**pybind11-trick**
@chrisb's "pybind11"-trick, which can be found [here](https://github.com/pybind/python_example/blob/2ed5a68759cd6ff5d2e5992a91f08616ef457b5c/setup.py#L9): With help of an indirection, one delays the call to `import numpy` until numpy is present during the setup-phase, i.e.:

```
class get_numpy_include(object):

    def __str__(self):
        import numpy
        return numpy.get_include()
...
my_c_lib_ext = setuptools.Extension(
    ...
    include_dirs=[get_numpy_include()]
)
```

Clever! The problem: it doesn't work with the Cython-compiler: somewhere down the line, Cython passes the `get_numpy_include`-object to `os.path.join(...,...)` which checks whether the argument is really a string, which it obviously isn't.

This could be fixed by inheriting from `str`, but the above shows the dangers of the approach in the long run - it doesn't use the designed mechanics, is brittle and may easily fail in the future.

**the classical [`build_ext`-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21621689/5769463)**

Which looks as following:

```
...
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def finalize_options(self):
        _build_ext.finalize_options(self)
        # Prevent numpy from thinking it is still in its setup process:
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())

setupttools.setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'build_ext':build_ext},
    ...
)
```

Yet also this solution doesn't work with cython-extensions, because `pyx`-files don't get recognized.

The real question is, how did `pyx`-files get recognized in the first place? The answer is [this part](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/a94ccbf404a79d56f9b171024dee361de9a948da/setuptools/command/build_ext.py#L15) of `setuptools.command.build_ext`:

```
...
try:
    # Attempt to use Cython for building extensions, if available
    from Cython.Distutils.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext
    # Additionally, assert that the compiler module will load
    # also. Ref #1229.
    __import__('Cython.Compiler.Main')
except ImportError:
    _build_ext = _du_build_ext
...
```

That means `setuptools` tries to use the Cython's build_ext if possible, and because the import of the module is delayed until `build_ext` is called, it founds Cython present.

The situation is different when `setuptools.command.build_ext` is imported at the beginning of the `setup.py` - the Cython isn't yet present and a fall back without cython-functionality is used.

**mixing up pybind11-trick and classical solution**

So let's add an indirection, so we don't have to import `setuptools.command.build_ext` directly at the beginning of `setup.py`:

```
....
# factory function
def my_build_ext(pars):
     # import delayed:
     from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext#
 
     # include_dirs adjusted: 
     class build_ext(_build_ext):
         def finalize_options(self):
             _build_ext.finalize_options(self)
             # Prevent numpy from thinking it is still in its setup process:
             __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
             import numpy
             self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
     
    #object returned:
    return build_ext(pars)
...
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'build_ext' : my_build_ext},
    ...
)
```

Comment: Subclassing `build_ext` is actually a pretty neat idea - this led me to another proposal, subclassing `build` instead of `build_ext`. Not that it would be less of a workaround (I'd prefer custom finalizing of `build_ext` too), but meh.

Comment: I was excited because your `pyproject.toml` solution seems much simpler, but when I tried to use it I still run into the issue where `numpy` can't be imported because it isn't installed yet when `setup.py` is processed.

My pyproject.toml:

```

Comment: @DanBlanchard you have to use pip for the installation in this case.

Answer (score 4):

One (hacky) suggestion would be using the fact that `extension.include_dirs` is first requested in `build_ext`, which is called after the setup dependencies are downloaded.

```
class MyExt(setuptools.Extension):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__include_dirs = []
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def include_dirs(self):
        import numpy
        return self.__include_dirs + [numpy.get_include()]

    @include_dirs.setter
    def include_dirs(self, dirs):
        self.__include_dirs = dirs


my_c_lib_ext = MyExt(
    name="my_c_lib",
    sources=["my_c_lib/some_file.pyx"]
)

setup(
    ...,
    setup_requires=['cython', 'numpy'],
)
```

---

#### Update

Another (less, but I guess still pretty hacky) solution would be overriding `build` instead of `build_ext`, since we know that `build_ext` is a subcommand of `build` and will always be invoked by `build` on installation. This way, we don't have to touch `build_ext` and leave it to Cython. This will also work when invoking `build_ext` directly (e.g., via `python setup.py build_ext` to rebuild the extensions inplace while developing) because [`build_ext` ensures all options of `build` are initialized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py#L133), and by coincidence, [`Command.set_undefined_options` first ensures the command has finalized](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/cmd.py#L287) (I know, `distutils` is a mess).

Of course, now we're misusing `build` - it runs code that belongs to `build_ext` finalization. However, I'd still probably go with this solution rather than with the first one, ensuring the relevant piece of code is properly documented.

```
import setuptools
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig


class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        # I stole this line from ead's answer:
        __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
        import numpy
        # or just modify my_c_lib_ext directly here, ext_modules should contain a reference anyway
        extension = next(m for m in self.distribution.ext_modules if m == my_c_lib_ext)
        extension.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())


my_c_lib_ext = setuptools.Extension(
    name="my_c_lib",
    sources=["my_c_lib/some_file.pyx"]
)

setuptools.setup(
    ...,
    ext_modules=[my_c_lib_ext],
    cmdclass={'build': build},
    ...
)
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, I wanted to both `pip install` and run `python setup.py build_ext`.

Comment: In latest python versions you may need to replace `__builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False` with `import builtins; builtins.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False`

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar with Cython import when cythonize is required in ext_modules=... of setup()?

Answer (score 2):

I found a very easy solution in [this post](https://luminousmen.com/post/resolve-cython-and-numpy-dependencies):

> Or you can stick to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5761. Here you install cython and numpy using setuptools.dist before actual setup:

```
from setuptools import dist
dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['Cython>=0.15.1', 'numpy>=1.10'])
```

Works well for me!