# setup_requires does not seem to install dependencies

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Maybe I don't understand the flow, but I can't manage to install dependencies to `setup.py` file before the script is actually run. My guess was that providing a `setup_requires` option to the `setup.py` file would install modules required by the setup file so that I can import them. Here my file:

```
import os
import numpy
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, Extension

# Cython library
ext = [Extension('sp.filters',  # location of the resulting .so
                 ['sp/filters.pyx'],
                 include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])]


setup(name='Filters',
      description="BlahBlah",
      long_description="BlahBlahBlah",
      packages=['filters'],
      ext_modules=cythonize(ext),
      setup_requires=[
        'cython',
        'numpy,
        'setuptools'
      ],
      install_requires=['numpy',
                        'numba',
                        'scipy',]
)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-uck5sw58/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        import numpy
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: You may find this question useful: [Add numpy.get_include() argument to setuptools without preinstalled numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117786)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `import numpy` (and `Cython`) before calling `setup()`. `setup()` doesn't have a chance to install anything.

In your case `setup_requires` cannot help. Install `numpy` and `Cython` before running `setup.py`. Or refactor `setup.py` to not import `numpy` and `Cython`.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped there were some magic around `pip install` that parse inside the setup file to find `setup_requires` required packages....