# Cython C-level interface of package: *.pxd files are not found

Tags: python, cython, python-packaging, python-extensions, cythonize

**In a nutshell**

I try to compile a cython extension called `extension2` that cimports a file `extension` from a self-created package. When building `extension2`, I get the error that `extension.pxd` is not found though this file is exactly at the sepcified path.

**Details**

I am building two packages involving cython, a package `A` and a package `B` that depends on `A`. `A` is a subpacke of a namespace package `nsp`. That is, the folder structure looks as follows:

```
├── nsp
│   └── A
|       ├── extension.pxd
|       ├── extension.pyx
│       └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

Here, `setup.py` reads as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension

# factory function
def my_build_ext(pars):
    # import delayed:
    from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

    # include_dirs adjusted: 
    class build_ext(_build_ext):
        def finalize_options(self):
            _build_ext.finalize_options(self)
            # Prevent numpy from thinking it is still in its setup process:
            __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
            import numpy
            self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())

    #object returned:
    return build_ext(pars)

extensions = [Extension(nsp.A.extension, ['nsp/A/extension.cpp'])]

setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext' : my_build_ext},
    setup_requires=['numpy'],
    install_requires=['numpy'], 
    packages=['nsp.A'],
    ext_modules=extensions
    package_data={
        'nsp/A': ['*.pxd', '*.pyx']
    },
)
```

The setup file is inspired by [add-numpy-get-include-argument-to-setuptools-without-preinstalled-numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117786/add-numpy-get-include-argument-to-setuptools-without-preinstalled-numpy) and [distributing-cython-modules](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules). The cython files were already successfully transformed to `.cpp` files with another script.

I install the the package `A` with

```
pip install .
```

in the directory of the `setup.py`. Everything works as desired, and I can find all files of the package under `...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\nsp\A`, including the `*.pxd` files.

Now I seek to create a `*.cpp` file for an `extension2` in order to package it later in the second package `B`. The file `extension2.pxd` reads

```
from nsp.A.extension cimport mymethod
```

The script to create the `*.cpp` file reads

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np
import sys
print(sys.executable)

NAME = 'extension2'
extensions = [Extension(NAME, [NAME+'.pyx'],
                        include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
                        )
              ]

setup(name=NAME,
      ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, language="c++", 
                              compiler_directives=compiler_directives),
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
      )
```

When I run this script with `python myscript build_ext --inplace`, I get an error indicating the `pxd` file is missing:

```
from nsp.A.extension cimport mymethod
^
------------------------------------------------------------

.\extension2.pxd:11:0: 'nsp\A\extension.pxd' not found
```

However, this file exists exactly there. (`sys.executable` is the `Anaconda3` folder that contains the installed package) How can I resolve the issue?

**Additional info**

I am using python 3.7 on Windows x64

Comment: And you are sure pip is the right pip? I.e. pip for python3.7 and not python 2?

Comment: Otherwise, check the python path in setup.py

Comment: @ead I am certain that I am using the correct Python installation. I have only one installation, and importing the compiled files (not the pxd) works well. For the same reason I believe the path in setup.py is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cython does not support [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) as of yet. That is, cython searches only subdirectories that contain a file `init.*`, whereby `*` can be anything from `py`, `pyc`, `pyx`, and `pxd`.

I have created a [bugtracker report for this issue](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3301), in case you want to follow up on whether the issue has been fixed in a newer version yet (I worked with Cython 0.29.14).

Until then, a workaround is to create an empty file `__init__.pxd` in the folder `nsp`. This file should be ignored by python, as it is not a `*.py` file, and lets cython search the subdirectories for packages. The file structure then reads as follows:

```
├── nsp
│   ├── __init__.pxd
│   └── A
|       ├── extension.pxd
|       ├── extension.pyx
│       └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

To install the additional file `__init__.pxd` in the namespace package, change the `packages` argument of `setup(...)` to `packages=['nsp', 'nsp.A']` and the `package_data` argument to `package_data={'': ['*.pxd', '*.pyx']}`.

**Edit:**

The bug has been known to the cython developers and will be fixed in version 3. See [Fix for cimport from PEP420 namespace](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2918).