# Warning when using dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['Cython', 'numpy'])

Tags: python, setuptools

I am using `Cython` and `numpy` in `setup.py`. However, it creates a problem with `setup.py` trying to use `cythonize` and `numpy` before it is actually installed. I found multiple answers to how to avoid it -> [Add numpy.get_include() argument to setuptools without preinstalled numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117786/add-numpy-get-include-argument-to-setuptools-without-preinstalled-numpy)

Literally the only workaround that worked for me is the following:

```
from setuptools import dist
dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['Cython', 'numpy'])
```

That did not work, but adding 'wheel' solved it for me:

```
from setuptools import dist
dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['wheel', 'Cython', 'numpy'])
```

However, I get the following warnings:

```
XXX\setup.py:13: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
!!

        ********************************************************************************
        Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
        ********************************************************************************

!!
  dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['wheel', 'Cython', 'numpy'])
  WARNING: The wheel package is not available
```

Is it save to ignore this warning? I am aware that `setup.py` is out-of-dated, I am planning to change it to `pyproject.toml` later. Is it caused just by me not using `pyproject.toml`?

What is the source of `WARNING: The wheel package is not available`? If `wheel` is actually added and seems to work properly?

Is there better solution for this issue, without yet changing to `pyproject.toml`?